# TTF Font Sizing Issue (Android canvas)

Tags: android, truetype

I am drawing text in my custom view with canvas.drawText() and the font is not scaled correctly according to the floating size I provide. The Font is drawn only in discrete sizes. Why is that and is there a way to scale a font with floating size ?

```
paint.setTextSize(textSize);
Log.d("DEBUG", "textSize : " + textSize);
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/times.ttf"));
```

As you can see in the following Illustration, the font changes suddenly from 3 to 2.
Is there a way to draw the font with 2.5f size ?

[image]

Comment: The illustration shows a sans-serif font, yet times is a serif font, and the result seems to show a kerning issue.  Can you confirm the font is loading correctly and you are talking about font size, rather than font kerning.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
paint.textSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12f, resources.displayMetrics)
```

this code sets 12sp text size to paint

Comment: There is not signiture for setTextSize(TypedValue, textSizeInFloat). There is only setTextSize(float). I am using the setTextSize from android.graphics.paint.

Comment: This can't help, because no matter what TypedValue.applyDimension is returning as a float, the font will be drawn as discrete integer. See my code. 3.02 -> Fontsize=3 , 2.88 -> Fontsize = 2.